# ElasticSearch searching hyphened text with whitespace instead dash on the query

Tags: elasticsearch, search, whitespace, hyphenation

I have indexed data (person) with firstName = "Jean-Marc", and I would like to be able to find this person using a combination of different queries, for example for the firstName "Jean-Marc" it should be possible to search with:
"Jean-Marc" and "Jean Marc" (with whitespace or dash)

Here is the mapping :

```
  "firstName": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer": "keyword_normalizer",
    "fields": {
      "analysed": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "hyphen_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "fielddata": true
      }
    }
  }
```

And the setting :

```
"char_filter": {
    "allowOnlyChar": {
        "pattern": "[^A-Za-z]",
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "replacement": " "
    }
}

"analyzer": {
    "hyphen_analyzers": {
        "filter": "lowercase",
        "char_filter": [
            "allowOnlyChar"
        ],
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard"
    }
}
```

I get the person when I keep the dash, but no result with whitespace query

I use elastic 6.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your analyser :

```
"char_filter": {
    "allowOnlyChar": {
        "pattern": "[^A-Za-z]",
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "replacement": " "
    }
}

"analyzer": {
    "yourAnalyzer": {
        "filter": "lowercase",
        "char_filter": [
            "allowOnlyChar"
        ],
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard"
    }
}
```

And of course index your documents with this analyser.
"analyzer": "yourAnalyzer"

link to doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, your suggestion seems not working when I use keyword type, I update the question with the global config

Comment: Oh my bad didnot see the keyword in mappings. Wathever you can set the analyzer to a keyword too, pretty simular: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing my tokenizer to keyword works fine